# Is it possible to do a reverse search replace on a string if you know the original pattern?

Tags: php, algorithm

I currently have an existing PHP string template mechanism that does a very simple parameter substitution. It works great, so consider the following:

**Template:**

```
{"name" : "The Person is called {$name}", "comments": "These are comments: {$comments}."}
```

**PHP Replace function:**

```
function replaceVariables($string, $values) { 
    $string_processed = preg_replace_callback(
        '~\{\$(.*?)\}~si',
        function($match) use ($values)
        {
            return str_replace($match[0], isset($values[$match[1]]) ? $values[$match[1]] : $match[0], $match[0]);
        },
        $string);
    return $string_processed;
}
```

So, running:

```
replaceVariables($myTemplate, ["name"=>"John", "comments"=>"Hello World"]);
replaceVariables($myTemplate, ["name"=>"Mary", "comments"=>"Another variation."]);
```

...works exactly as expected and produces the desired result. However, how about if I wanted to "reverse engineer" back to the input parameter array!

For example, suppose I no longer had access to the `["name"=>"John", "comments"=>"Hello World"]` parameter array. However, I do have the template and the output json string. Can anyone think of a way to reconstitute the original input array?

Been thinking about this for ages and cannot think of an elegant way of doing it!
Any ideas?
Ta,
Jab

Comment: I don't know PHP and the specifics of the functions, so this is a comment in general. You can't do what you desire because if the starting string for reversing has the pattern you want to replace, i.e. `Mary` but `Mary` was in the original string then you have replaced `Mary` when `Mary` should not be replaced. You could keep a history of changes to each value in the file, something like Git, but then is that what you really want to do?

Comment: @GuyCoder I don’t think it is necessarily impossible. Even if the `name` in the first example was `Person` (as the literal value), you would get `The Person is called Person` in the result. But we _know_, from analyzing the template, that the part `The Person is called ` was static to begin with - so only the second occurrence of `Person` _can_ be “data” in the first place. I guess the solution needs to be something along these lines - analyze the template patterns, to figure out which parts in the results were static, and which resulted from dynamically inserted values.

Comment: @Jablalr what _exactly_ do you have as input data here now, when you say _“the output json string”_? Individual instances of `{"name" : "The Person is called John", "comments": "These are comments: Hello World."}`? Multiple of them? (You have shown _two_ example calls of your replace function.) As strings, wrapped into an additional array level, …?

Comment: @CBroe I don't think it's so straightforward with a one-to-one mapping. Say your template was `{address} and {country} country` and your output JSON had `abc district and xyz city and DEF country`. Now, how would you know you have to take the second `and` and not the first one?

Comment: @vivek_23 that this won’t work properly, if there can be any ambiguity like the one you pointed out, is clear. The templates shown as examples so far only seemed to contain a single placeholder each, that would reduce the complexity quite a bit. OP would have to clarify if that will always be the case.

Comment: @CBroe Fair enough. Yes, if OP confirms if no such ambiguity would exist, then it should be far simpler.

Comment: All, thanks for comments and feedback. @vivek_23, there would be lots of complexity unfortunately. The sample provided is pretty simple, but in reality, its probably 10's of variable elements that I am dealing with. In some cases each variable might represent a single word, but in others, it could be an entire sentence or paragraph! Feels like what I was thinking of is not possible for practicality reasons?

Comment: @Jablalr Then it's not possible especially with the added complexity of ambiguity.